# Simple DOB in HTML to calculate Age

Tags: html, mysql, jscript

Am a total newbie.

Here's what I have:

In html, I have a form that says

Birthdate (MMDDYY):

where the date is entered as 021304 (for Feb 13, 2004)

I use $_POST in php to send this to a CHAR(6) field in MySQL

How do I then simply echo the age (as of today, in years only) in 1) the same html window after the person types it in, and 2) in a separate html page by retrieving form data from MySQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try following codes.These code worked for me.

HTML

```
<input type="date" name="dob" id="dob"/>
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" readonly  />
```

AgeCalculation.php

```
 <?php 
 $birthday=$_POST['dob'];
 list($year , $month , $date) = explode("-",$birthday);
 $YearDiff = date("Y") - $year;
 if(date("m") < $month || (date("m") == $month && date("d") < $date))
 {
$YearDiff--;
echo ($YearDiff);
 }
 else
 { 
echo ($YearDiff);
 }
 ?>
```

Jquery Code :

```
$("#dob").change(function(){ 
var birthdate=$(this).val();
$.post("AgeCalculation.php",{dob1:birthdate},function(data){
$("#age").val(data);
    });
});
```